# Xcode Simulator is displaying the screen of a project I deleted instead of the project I am working on

Tags: xcode, simulator

I am new to this Xcode program (as well as stackoverflow) and I am already running into this problem where my simulator is switching screens from the project I am currently working on to a project that I previously worked on. I decided to delete my previous project but it is still showing up in the simulator. It's as if it is thinking my current project should look like my previous one.

Here is what I tried to fix it but didn't work:

- I already tried using a different simulator and going into the "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" folder and deleted the projects I didn't want including the cache folder.
- I also tried long-pressing the old app in the simulator and deleting it that way but that didn't work.
- I also tried command+shift+k but nope. :(
- I also tried reseting the cache according to several websites that I looked on, but when it said to go into the simulator and "Reset Content and Settings" I couldn't find it and instead found "Erase All Content and Settings" under the Hardware menu tab. I tried it and I am still getting my deleted project showing up in my simulator.
- I also tried putting this "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode" into the terminal and it's giving me "Domain (com.apple.dt.Xcode) not found."

I am currently using Xcode version 11 while using a iPhoneXr simulator. I don't want to re-install the entire app because I'm sure to run into the same problem again, nor do I want to try testing on my actual phone. I looked everywhere for an answer and I am getting nothing so I am stuck with an Xcode with a funky simulator. Am I missing something or am I not looking into the correct folders??? If anyone has an answer to this problem please help me.

************ UPDATE ************:

I found out that my simulator is working correctly... somewhat... 
It's just that I have mistaken what the simulator shows on the screen depending on what's in the ContentView.swift file. When I first started Xcode, I followed a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jniJeamcIUU&list=PLMRqhzcHGw1ZkH8RuznGMS0NZs0jWQQ5a&index=1 where he showed me how to put Hello World on the page. It worked but then I wanted to start a new project, and when I started this new project in the simulator, I still got Hello World on my screen instead of what I put down in my LaunchScreen.storyboard. Then I deleted my old Hello World project and still got the same screen in my new project. I mistook this as the simulator re-opening a deleted project, but my current project was actually reading from the swift file (which held a Text("Hello World")) and opening whatever was on it which caused the switch in screens from my LaunchScreen.storyboard to the Hello World page again. At least I think that is what was happening??? Again, I'm completely new to Xcode and swift so how do I make the simulator show and stay on my LaunchScreen.storyboard? I just have a simple StackView with buttons and a label in it. I didn't set the buttons to work yet in the backend.

(Just in case) My ContentView.swift file holds this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I started the new project I also got two other files AppDelegate.swift and SceneDelegate.swift and I have absolutely no idea what these files do. I didn't do anything to them either.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`. This file is then recreated by Xcode.

Then you should try `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

A more surgical (but less certain) fix would be the following:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTSourceControlAccountDefaultsKey
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried removing that file and restarting the simulator but I got the same problem. Then I used both the deletion commands in the terminal and it didn’t show me the error message but nothing changed with the simulator.